# Is git-merge output correct?

Tags: git, merge, path, output, git-merge

I'm trying to analyze the history of merges in ANTLR4 repository of Github (https://github.com/antlr/antlr4). However, there is an output that does not make sense for me when I try to replay the merge fe1d61d9dba9f202982da85606cbb7493ce7bae8. So I wonder if somebody can help me.

The merge fe1d61d9dba9f202982da85606cbb7493ce7bae8 has two parents: 103dc662c  and 31d21ff4d. Thus, to replay the merge I execute the following steps:

1. git checkout 103dc662c; and
2. git merge 31d21ff4d.

In this case, there are some conflicting files. However, the file "repository path"/runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go show the following conflict:

```
// @param recognizer the parser instance
// @param e the recognition exception
//
<<<<<<< HEAD:runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go
func (d *DefaultErrorStrategy) ReportInputMisMatch(recognizer Parser, e *InputMisMatchException) {
        var msg = "mismatched input " + d.GetTokenErrorDisplay(e.offendingToken) +
=======
func (this *DefaultErrorStrategy) ReportInputMisMatch(recognizer Parser, e *InputMisMatchException) {
        var msg = "mismatched input " + this.GetTokenErrorDisplay(e.offendingToken) +
>>>>>>> 31d21ff:runtime/Go/src/antlr4/ErrorStrategy.go
                " expecting " + e.getExpectedTokens().StringVerbose(recognizer.GetLiteralNames(), recognizer.GetSymbolicNames(), false)
        recognizer.NotifyErrorListeners(msg, e.offendingToken, e)
}
```

When I try to open the original files in the parent's versions, the file in the left version (103dc662c) **<<<<<<< HEAD:runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go** exists, but the file in the right version (31d21ff4d) does not exists **>>>>>>> 31d21ff:runtime/Go/src/antlr4/ErrorStrategy.go**. After investigate, I could realize that the file in the right version also is in the path runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go.

Am I misinterpreting something?

Thanks in advance,
Gleiph

Answer (score 0):

Let's repeat the setup:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/antlr/antlr4
Cloning into 'antlr4'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 2, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
^Rceiving objects:  21% (24258/115511), 16.64 MiB | 3.15 MiB/s    /s   
remote: Total 115511 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 115509
Receiving objects: 100% (115511/115511), 61.89 MiB | 3.13 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (67916/67916), done.
$ git checkout -b tmp 103dc662c
```

All OK so far.  Now we'll get the merge conflict **along with a lot of messages we should pay attention to:**

```
$ git merge 31d21ff4d
Auto-merging tool/resources/org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/Go/Go.stg
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in tool/resources/org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/Go/Go.stg
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Utils.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Trees.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Tree.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Transition.go
CONFLICT (rename/delete): runtime/Go/src/antlr4/TraceListener.go deleted in HEAD and renamed to runtime/Go/src/antlr/TraceListener.go in 31d21ff4d. Version 31d21ff4d of runtime/Go/src/antlr/TraceListener.go left in tree.
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/TokenStream.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/TokenSource.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Token.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/SemanticContext.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/RuleContext.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Recognizer.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/PredictionMode.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/PredictionContext.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ParserRuleContext.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ParserATNSimulator.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Parser.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/LexerActionExecutor.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/LexerAction.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/LexerATNSimulator.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Lexer.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/LL1Analyzer.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/IntervalSet.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/IntStream.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/InputStream.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/FileStream.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/Errors.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorListener.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/DiagnosticErrorListener.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/DFAState.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/DFASerializer.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/DFA.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/CommonTokenStream.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/CommonTokenFactory.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/CharStream.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ATNType.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ATNState.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ATNSimulator.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ATNDeserializer.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ATNDeserializationOptions.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ATNConfigSet.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ATNConfig.go
Auto-merging runtime/Go/src/antlr/ATN.go
Removing pb/src/parser/T.g4
Removing pb/src/parser/T.g
Removing pb/src/parser/S.g4
Removing pb/src/parser/M.g4
Removing pb/src/parser/JSON.g4
Removing pb/src/parser/Expr.g4
Removing pb/src/parser/Arithmetic.g4
Removing pb/src/parser/.gitignore
Removing pb/src/input
Removing pb/src/Test.go
Removing antlr.go
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Note the *rename/delete* conflict mentioned early on:

> ```
> CONFLICT (rename/delete): runtime/Go/src/antlr4/TraceListener.go deleted in HEAD
> and renamed to runtime/Go/src/antlr/TraceListener.go in 31d21ff4d. Version
> 31d21ff4d of runtime/Go/src/antlr/TraceListener.go left in tree.
> ```

(line-breaks added by me).

> When I try to open the original files in the parent's versions, the file in the left version ... exists,

That's fine, but as it's clear that at least one side renamed at least *some* files, we should expect that these files might have different names in the three input commits.

> ... the file in the right version ... is in the path runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go.

I find this one in `runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go`, in `MERGE_HEAD` aka `31d21ff4db8ddcf76bae1b865cd568621bfd5b4d`.

However, in the *merge base* commit:

```
$ git merge-base --all HEAD MERGE_HEAD
3406acabe51e89c57fc26aca02aeb7cbc30119bd
```

the repository has it in `runtime/Go/src/antlr4/ErrorStrategy.go`:

```
git ls-tree -r 3406acabe51e89c57fc26aca02aeb7cbc30119bd | grep ErrorStrategy.go
100644 blob aed0ef94b5409f8035897496610446a5cbb52ef2    runtime/Go/src/antlr4/ErrorStrategy.go
```

In other words, it appears that both of the two merge input commits have followed the same rename pattern here.  The diff from merge base to HEAD, and the diff from merge base to `31d21ff4d`, both renamed the `antl4` subdirectory to `antlr`.

This is all perfectly normal.  If you are doing manual merge resolution, you might find it helpful to set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`.  If you prefer to have Git find the files for you, consider using `git mergetool` to extract the input files: it is supposed to automatically find the merge-base, HEAD, and MERGE_HEAD files for you.

Answer (score 0):

Torek,

Thanks a lot. However, in the Git merge documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge), there is the following example:

```
Here are lines that are either unchanged from the common
ancestor, or cleanly resolved because only one side changed.
<<<<<<< yours:sample.txt
Conflict resolution is hard;
let's go shopping.
=======
Git makes conflict resolution easy.
>>>>>>> theirs:sample.txt
And here is another line that is cleanly resolved or unmodified.
```

So I would expect something like:

```
// @param recognizer the parser instance
// @param e the recognition exception
//
<<<<<<< HEAD:runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go
func (d *DefaultErrorStrategy) ReportInputMisMatch(recognizer Parser, e *InputMisMatchException) {
        var msg = "mismatched input " + d.GetTokenErrorDisplay(e.offendingToken) +
=======
func (this *DefaultErrorStrategy) ReportInputMisMatch(recognizer Parser, e *InputMisMatchException) {
        var msg = "mismatched input " + this.GetTokenErrorDisplay(e.offendingToken) +
>>>>>>> 31d21ff:runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go
                " expecting " + e.getExpectedTokens().StringVerbose(recognizer.GetLiteralNames(), recognizer.GetSymbolicNames(), false)
        recognizer.NotifyErrorListeners(msg, e.offendingToken, e)
}
```

In this case both branches are renamed. However, the line **>>>>>>> 31d21ff:runtime/Go/src/antlr/ErrorStrategy.go** is **>>>>>>> 31d21ff:runtime/Go/src/antlr4/ErrorStrategy.go** in the real example. Does it make sense to you?

Thanks,
Gleiph